# product special price changes in checkout page opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am trying to add special price for my product in **OpenCart 2.0.1.1** with custom theme. on first time it will show fine. but, When I click on add to cart button and trying to buy that product in checkout page special price is getting disappeared and it shows product MRP price, when I return to same product page special price is not shown, it only shows my MRP price.

Comment: Please add code sample. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a correct "Customer Group" when setting a special price for an item, if you delete this customer group later this special price will disappear.